Sampled weights in Qiskit Circuit Knitting Toolbox
From the Qiskit Circuit Knitting Toolbox:
"Each weight with absolute value above a threshold of 1/num_samples will be evaluated exactly. The remaining low-probability elements – those in the tail of the distribution – will then be sampled"
I understand that the elements of the quasiprobability distribution with lower probability are randomly sampled, but why the related weights can't be evaluated exactly? As far as I know, it is the product of the weights of the quasi-probability decompositions of the non local gates (so an operation that scales polynomially with the number of non-local gates).
For example, if I have a quantum circuit with 20 non-local Rzz gates, for num_samples=10, I get
[(0.9996296479727091, <WeightType.EXACT: 1>), (0.1125153527556628, <WeightType.SAMPLED: 2>), (-0.1125153527556628, <WeightType.SAMPLED: 2>), (-0.1125153527556628, <WeightType.SAMPLED: 2>)]
For num_samples=1000 I get
[(0.999629647972708, <WeightType.EXACT: 1>), (0.008445856626090266, <WeightType.EXACT: 1>), (-0.008445856626090266, <WeightType.EXACT: 1>), (0.008445856626090266, <WeightType.EXACT: 1>), (-0.008445856626090266, <WeightType.EXACT: 1>), (0.0072323017707976315, <WeightType.EXACT: 1>),......, (0.0013075093858233033, <WeightType.SAMPLED: 2>), (-0.0013075093858233033, <WeightType.SAMPLED: 2>)]
Therefore, the weights sampled in the first case are really different for the exact ones, and I do not understand how they calculate them and why they do not calculate the exact weights.
